# Problemas al actualizar un JTable

Tags: java

*Tengo un  meotodo JTable para cargar datos desde un ArrayList.*

```
public void llenarTablaAlimentos(){
    String nombreColumnas [] = {"Platos","Precio","Cantidad de platos"};
    String informacionColumnas [][] = new String[alimentos.size()][3];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < alimentos.size(); i++) {
        informacionColumnas[i][0] = alimentos.get(i).getNombre();
        informacionColumnas[i][1] = String.valueOf(alimentos.get(i).getPrecio());
        informacionColumnas[i][2] = String.valueOf(alimentos.get(i).getCantidadPlatos());    
    }
    
    jTablePlatos.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(informacionColumnas,nombreColumnas));
}
```

*Otro método que se activa con un botón de crear un nuevo Objeto que se agrega al ArrayList*

```
public void guardarAlimento(String nombre,Integer cantidad,Integer precio){
    Alimentos alimentoGuardar = new Alimentos(nombre,precio,cantidad);
    alimentos.add(alimentoGuardar);
    llenarTablaAlimentos();
}
```

*Ahora, cuando agrego un nuevo objeto a la ArrayList y llamó nuevamente a la función llenarTablaAlimentos no me actualiza la Jtable.*

Comment: Haz un debug del código imprimiendo los datos en ambos métodos para verificar si están funcionando. De todos modos, el código no queda optimizado teniendo que leer cada vez el array para llenar la tabla cada vez desde cero. Lo propio sería agregar una nueva fila a la tabla desde `guardarAlimento()`. Revisa [este ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3549341/5587982) para más detalles.

Comment: Si, en ambos métodos se están generando datos. Me gusta la idea en verdad, voy a aplicarla. Gracias.